# Google Cloud CDN does not overwrite cache-control header when response is 304 Not Modified?

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

We will use Google Cloud CDN to cache the objects in the backend bucket as follows.

```
$ gcloud compute backend-buckets describe xxx-backend-bucket
bucketName: xxx
cdnPolicy:
  cacheMode: CACHE_ALL_STATIC
  clientTtl: 0
  defaultTtl: 60
  maxTtl: 60
  negativeCaching: false
  requestCoalescing: true
  serveWhileStale: 300
description: ''
enableCdn: true
kind: compute#backendBucket
name: xxx-backend-bucket
```

The metadata of the bucket object is set to `cache-control: max-age=31536000`.

On the first request from the client, the CDN will return a 200 response and override the cache-control with `max-age=0`. This is the expected behavior.

However, if there is an `if-modified-since` in the request header from the client, the CDN will return a 304 response and the cache-control in the response header will be set to `max-age=31536000`. The expected behavior is to set `max-age=0`.

I'm having trouble with 304 responses because the cache-control is not overridden and is cached by the client for an unintentionally long time.

Is this a CDN specification?

Comment: I would suggest you file a [Private Cloud CDN issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=491342&template=1160995) on the [Google issue trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that GCP Support can take a closer look.

Comment: @Tariq Thanks for the advice, I created an issue in IssueTracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193686622

Comment: This issue has been resolved.